# Statistics and probability: ice cream selection

Tags: probability, statistics

My stats test is tomorrow, and my professor emailed me a question to consider.

> Ben gets a three-scoop ice cream cone. There's a .4 probability that the middle scoop is chocolate, .2 prob that the top scoop is chocolate, and .6 prob that the bottom scoop is chocolate. The different scoops are mutually independent.
>
> What's the probability that Ben gets a cone with exactly one scoop of chocolate? (How about exactly two scoops?)

For one scoop, I initially multiplied the probs to get .048, but that seems wrong. I think I need to create a union. $(T\cap NB \cap NM) \cup (NT \cap NB \cap M) \cup (NT \cap B \cap NM).$

T=Top, B = Bottom, M = Middle, NT = Not Top, etc.

I'm not sure how to get the values, assuming this is correct. Do I need to create a Venn Diagram with three circles? How? A intersects B in 2 places, etc.

Comment: By the way, $0.048$ is the probability of getting exactly *three* scoops of chocolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a union of disjoint events; the probability of that is the sum of probabilities of the events.

Each of those events is an intersection of (mutually) independent events; the probability of such is the product of the probabilities of the independent events.

$$\begin{align} &\mathsf P((A\cap B^c\cap C^c)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap C^c)\cup(A^c\cap B^c\cap C))\\ =~& \mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B^c)\mathsf P(C^c)+\mathsf P(A^c)\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C^c)+\mathsf P(A^c)\mathsf P(B^c)\mathsf P(C)\end{align}$$

Comment: Other than recognizing that .6+.4+.2 must be wrong (because it totals to 1.2), how do you know to add this union, but with three scoops you multiply?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon You always *add* with a *union* and *multiply* with an *intersection*.  If the union is of *disjoint* events then just add, *otherwise* use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.  If the intersection is of *mutually independent* events, just multiply, *otherwise* use conditional probability.